# Bash JSON variable to SQLite

Tags: json, bash, sqlite

I can't really figure this out - the SQL query outputed is not valid

```
key="test"
payload=$(gzip -ckqd ./temp.json.gz | jq -c . | sed 's/"/\\"/g')

printf 'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ("%s", "%s")' "$key" "$payload" | sqlite3 ./temp.db
```

Obiously the $payload variable is a json string (can have single and double quotes etc)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for strings for starters.

Comment: Anyways, I think your best approach is to write a simple perl or python script that takes three arguments - the database, key, and json, and does the inserting using the normal parameter binding approach, to avoid all issues with quotes, commas, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings are delimited not with double quotes but with single quotes.

Inside a string, the only special character is the single quote itself, and it must be escaped not with a backslash, but with another quote:

```
... sed "s/'/''/g"
```